# Which is the correct use of 'no'

Tags: word-choice

Editing a document and wondering which is correct?

> There have been no historical digs on the pipeline.

OR

> There have not been any historical digs on the pipeline.

A lot of the document uses 'there have been no'. I'm just wondering if it is correct; it sounds funny to me.

Comment: Which is correct, mocha fudge or mint chocolate chip?

Comment: @DigitalChris: Those two choices seem different. Are the two sentences in the question different in meaning? I think they are both correct and they mean exactly the same. It seems rather a question of whether "chips and fish" and fish and chips" are both correct. In that case they mean the same, but one is idiomatic, the other is not. The two sentences that Eleskelly wrote, however, are both common and natural, I believe.

Comment: @oerkelens They are both two flavours of the same thing. ;)  ... the attempted point being that they are both equally fine.

Comment: They are different, in structure, but they mean the same thing. There's just a different choice of determiners, is all. Like the difference between _all the people_ and _all of the people_. The illusion that there must be a correct answer, or that one of two sentences is more correct than the other, is a fallacy. Authors make choices representing their speech habits.

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences mean the same thing, and both are grammatical.

I agree with you that the first sounds less natural, but according to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%20have%20been%20no%2C%20there%20have%20not%20been%20any&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20have%20been%20no%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20have%20not%20been%20any%3B%2Cc0) it's actually much more common.

Comment: Yes, both are idiomatic; whether one sounds more natural than the other will depend on context and dialect. To me, the first one sounds more natural.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are correct (grammatical) but *There have been no historical digs on the pipeline* is more formal than *There have not been any historical digs on the pipeline*.

Quirk in *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (p783) states:

> In all cases, the combination of *not* and the non-assertive word (*any,
>   anything, anywhere*, etc.) is more colloquial and idiomatic than the
>   negative variant (*no*).

This is confirmed by Peters in *The Cambridge Guide to English Usage* (p374), who writes:

> ... researchers found that *not...any* was the preferred form in
>   conversational English in the UK, making it very familiar to British
>   ears.